# Сохранение потокобезопасности

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Сделал класс, который необходимо сделать потокобезопасным. Залочил везде, где идут изменения поля класса, но, как я понял, этого недостаточно. Что ещё можно сделать?
Сам класс:

```
template<class T>
class queue
{

private:
    std::vector<T> q;
    std::mutex lock;

public:

    //конструктор и деструктор
    queue() {};
    ~queue() {
        lock.lock();
        q.clear();
        lock.unlock();
    };

    //добавление в очередь
    void push(T obj)
    {
        lock.lock();

        if (std::find(q.begin(), q.end(), obj) == q.end())
            this->q.push_back(obj);

        lock.unlock();
    }

    //получение из очереди + удаление
    T pop()
    {

        if (q.size() != 0) 
        {
            T tmp = q[0];
            lock.lock();
            q.erase(q.begin());
            lock.unlock();
            return tmp;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    //получение из очереди без удаления
    T front()
    {
        if (q.size() != 0) 
        {
            T tmp = q[0];
            return tmp;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    //получить размер очереди
    int size()
    {
        return q.size();
    }

    //очищение
    void clear()
    {
        lock.lock();
        q.clear();
        lock.unlock();
    }

};
```

Comment: (1) Залочили не все. (size() и копирование пользовательского типа уже не атомарные операции). (2)  Не учли вероятность выброса исключения из конструктора копирования пользовательского типа. (Пользуйтесь std::lock_guard или unique_lock.). (3) Даже если операции атомарные, но их в методе несколько, то все равно нужно лочить, поскольку состояние объекта может измениться между  вызовами этих атомарных методов. (см. вашу реализацию pop.)

Comment: Если к этому классу будут частые обращения, он превратится в тормоз и вас скушает закон Амдала. Подумайте над использованием lock-free структур данных.

Comment: lock-fre ещё не значит, что быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Там где просто происходит чтение, также лучше лочить. К примеру, кто то позвал front,  а другой поток позвал clear. Если все удачно сойдется, то получите исключение (очистка может произойти как раз между проверкой размера и собственно возвратом значения.

Также вместо ручного lock/unlock лучше повспользоваться RAII механизмами. Например, таким

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(lock);
```

и такую строку можно просто вставлять в начала каждой функции. А по выходу с функции unlock будет вызван автоматом.

```
T front()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(lock);
    if (q.size() != 0) 
    {
        T tmp = q[0];
        return tmp;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Если продолжать размышлять в том же ключе, то скоро станет понятно, что функция  size может использоваться исключительно в отладочно-информационном режиме. А строить на базе нее какую то логику - наивно. Если есть много-много (даже двох бывает достаточно) потоков, то они легко могут постоянно модифицировать размер.